# Detect face, get the boarder of face

Tags: python, image-processing, detection

I am a new to python. I'm trying to detect face and find the boundaries of the face.
How to make it? It can be a number of points that are the border of the face.

I want to obtain something like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to so! -) If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from http://fideloper.com/facial-detection:

> We can use openCV for facial detection. OpenCV is written in C, but
>   there are [bindings for Python](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) and actually PHP.

```
import cv2

def detect(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("/vagrant/detect/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
    rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.3, 4, cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, (20,20))

    if len(rects) == 0:
        return [], img
    rects[:, 2:] += rects[:, :2]
    return rects, img

def box(rects, img):
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in rects:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (127, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2.imwrite('/vagrant/img/detected.jpg', img);

rects, img = detect("/vagrant/img/one.jpg")
box(rects, img)
```

The original image:
[image]

With faces detected
[image]

Comment: I know it, but i want to get borders in the form lines not like rectangle. I want to get more precise boundaries. I want to obtain something like this http://my-files.ru/sxy798

Comment: ок,i am waiting for answer